# Make brackets automatic start new line

Tags: android, android-studio, editor, preferences, brackets

Sorry if I was not able to describe in the title how I like to do; I know that in AndroidStudio there is a way to use this brackets notation

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

instead this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

In other words I like that the first bracket of any method, class etc starts a new line. I know that it is possibile in preferences > editor but I'm not able to remember how I have to change.
Thanks a lot and sorry for the stupid question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | Java | Wrapping and Braces | Braces Placement

Change "End of Line" to "Next Line"

Comment: Glad I could help.  Only reason I knew where it was is it was the first thing I did when starting to program in studio as well.