# Make braces automatically start at new line

Tags: java, eclipse

I asked this same question about Android Studio, now I'm looking for an answer in Eclipse. I'd like the IDE to be able to "transform" this

```
public class While {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

into this

```
public class While 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    }
}
```

In other words, I'd like that the first braces of any method, class etc starts at a new line. I know that in Android Studio it's possible ([see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641275/make-brackets-automatic-start-new-line)), and I suppose that would be the same also for Eclipse.

Comment: check this http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fcodestyle%2Fref-preferences-formatter.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse and curly braces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236531/eclipse-and-curly-braces)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can configure the formatter that Eclipse uses.

In the "Windows > Preferences" dialog-box, go into "Java > Code Style > Formatter" and click "Edit". In the "Braces" tab, you will be able configure how braces are formatted for every type and methods.

For your use-case, you need to select "Next line" for classes and method declarations. Here's a picture:

[image]

If you are currently using the Eclipse built-in formatter, you will have to name this new formatter and then save it.

Comment: Moreover: If you turn on "Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Save Actions > Format source code", you'll find that Eclipse will format the code automatically every time you save a source file.

Answer (score 0):

Window | Preferences | Java | Code Style | Formatter | New Profile | Braces | Position

Change "Same line" to "Next line"

At the New Profile stage -> You have to create a new profile, import existing profile.